# Python nested list (2D array) referencing

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested, 2d

Looking at my code... why isn't my first nested list (grid1) the same as the 2nd nested list (grid2)? Why is the intilisation different?
For a game I want a 4 by 6 grid with each element having the value 'x' except grid[0][0] to be assigned to 'O'. This works in *grid2* but not in *grid1*. Why is the referencing & list different as it looks the same?

```
#setup grid1 (4x6 2D nested list) populating x's in all positions
grid1 =[["x"]*4]*6]

grid1[0][0]="O"      #assign row 1, column 1 'O'
print(grid1)
```

outputs

```
[['O', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['O', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['O', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['O', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['O', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['O', 'x', 'x', 'x']]
```

yet this implementation...

```
grid2 = []  
for row in range(0,6):
    grid2.append([])
    for column in range(0,4):
        grid2[row].append("x")

grid2[0][0]="O"

print(grid2)
```

outputs correctly

```
[['O', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]
```

What is the difference & why are they different?

Comment: In the `grid2` you are creating a new list for each iteration. In `grid1` you are simply referencing the same list multiple times. In `grid1`, all the lists are actually the same object in memory.

Comment: Try printing `id()` of each list in `grid1`. You will see the same `id` printed every time.

Comment: Thank you. Makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for grid1 in the line [["x"]*4]*6, the '*6' operation creates a list with six ["x","x","x","x"] but are the same reference.
This means changing any of the six ["x","x","x","x"] will change the others since they refer to the same object in memory.

You construct your own list class that overrides **mul**() to deep copy the lists prior during list multiplication.

Comment: To be precise, you cannot change any of these "x", as strings are immutable objects. You can only replace it with something else. The behaviour the OP is seeing is not caused by all "x"es being the same object, but rather by his inner lists (rows of the 2D array) being the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
grid3 = [ ["x"] * 4 for i in range(4) ]
grid3[0][0]="O"
print(grid3)
```

to achieve your goal in a more concise way.

Comment: That was my next question, thank you kindly. Love a bit of list comp.